# Having an Object-Oriented mindset to verify a programs arguments

Tags: c++, arguments

I need to verify the options passed to my program that looks like such:

```
./prog -n teamName -p port -h host
```

I am coding a client in C++ and, apparently, verified these parameters in a C-like fashion. Being rather new to C++ it is very important to me to have the right mindset when developing something in an Object-oriented manner.

As an example, here is how I am doing this verification so far:

```
int     verify_arguments(int ac, char **av)
{
  int           i;
  std::string   arg;
  std::string   team_name;
  int           port;
  std::string   ip("0");

  i = 1;
  while (i < ac)
    {
      arg = av[i];
      if (arg.compare("-n") == 0)
        {
          if ((team_name = verify_n(av, i)) == "")
            return (-1);
          i++;
        }
      else if (arg.compare("-p") == 0)
        {
          if ((port = verify_p(av, i)) == -1)
            return (-1);
          i++;
        }
      else if (arg.compare("-h") == 0)
        {
          if ((ip = verify_h(av, i)) == "")
            return (-1);
          i++;
        }
      else
        {
          std::cerr << "The option " << arg << " does not exist." << std::endl;
          return (-1);
        }
      i++;
    }
  std::cout << "Team name is: " << team_name << "\nPort is: " << port << "\nIP is: " << ip << std::endl;
  if (port != -1 && ip.compare("KO") != 0)
    connect_to_server(team_name, port, ip);
  return (0);
}
```

It is rather obvious why I wish to change this completely to fit the C++ style.

What is the best way to do it? When it comes to C++ arguments verification, what is the right path to take?

Comment: have a look at boost::program_options - it's been solved for you.

Comment: C++ is not an object-oriented language, it's a multiparadigm language thay supports OOP among other things.

Comment: Thank you for these informations, I'll be sure to check out boost::program_options.

Comment: This question might be better over at codereview.